# Getting Elevation / Altitude using Flutter Plugin Geolocator

Tags: flutter, geolocator

I am trying to get the GPS height off an Android phone using the Flutter plugin Geolocator without success. The phone I have has a barometer sensor and I have other installed apps on the phone that provide GPS altitude, so I know it's not the device.

This is the main.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: ElevationApp(),
    );
  }
}

class ElevationApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const ElevationApp({super.key});

  @override
  _ElevationAppState createState() => _ElevationAppState();
}

class _ElevationAppState extends State<ElevationApp> {
  double? _elevation;
  double? _lat;
  double? _long;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getElevation();
  }

  Future<void> _getElevation() async {
    try {
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
      );

      _elevation = position.altitude;
      _lat = position.latitude;
      _long = position.longitude;

      debugPrint('$_elevation');
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error getting elevation: $e");
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Elevation App'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Elevation:',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              _elevation != null ? '$_elevation meters' : 'Fetching elevation...',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),

            const Text(
              'at position:',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              _long != null ? 'Long: $_long' : 'Fetching position...',
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
        Text(
          _lat != null ? 'Lat: $_lat' : 'Fetching position...',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _getElevation,
                child:
            const Text('Get Location Again'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

No matter what I do I just cannot get the elevation to read, it always returns **0.0**

My AndroidManifest has the required permission set:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application...
```

The application is allowing access to Location services and it returns the latitude and longitude everytime.

Any ideas anyone :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK feel a bit stupid but I have solved my issue.

Leaving this here in case anyone else has the same problem.

So I have been testing the Geolocator plugin on several devices. On my iPhone it works and I get the altitude but the Android just kept giving 0.0.....that is until I took it outside and walked around.

Strange that sitting on my desk it gives lat and long but not altitude until we go for a stroll...:-)